# How to stop players joining my Minecraft PC server under my name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I am on my Minecraft PC server a player has come on under my name and has had op and my rank. After I ban them they are able to change there names and come back I keep banning them and they keep coming back. Not really sure what to do.

Comment: Were you using IP bans or username bans?

Comment: Or UUID bans? IP bans are pretty much useless by themselves, you want a combination of an IP Ban + A UUID ban. It takes like 2-3 minutes to change ur IP

Answer (score 3):

You could try running your server with online mode (which means you might have to purchase a copy of Minecraft) so that players have to authenticate (proof that they're themself) themselves before they can join.

Otherwise a plugin [like this](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/authme-reloaded) (one that prevents play until you separately authenticate yourself after logging in) that prevents others from reusing a taken name also works.

Otherwise, what you'll have to live with it, and ban yourself (to stop others from using your name) and deop yourself whenever you log out.

---

To set your server to online mode, go to your [`server.properties`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties) file and edit:

```
online-mode=false
```

to:

```
online-mode=true
```

Either that or change your account's password and secure your email address.

Comment: I own a Minecraft Premium account. How do I set my server to online mode?

Comment: @SnoopyGames See update.

Comment: @Snoopy There is nothing called a "premium account"! If you've bought it under that name, immediately call your bank to refund the payment, because you've been scammed! Only buy accounts directly from minecraft.net!

Comment: @aytimothy Running a server in online mode doesn't require an account, but of course joining it does.

Comment: @Fabian Röling I was on the assumption he was using an offline server because the username problem shouldn't exist unless (1) someone has access to his account, or (2) his server doesn't do authentication. This applies to both the Win10/XBL and Java editions.

Comment: @FabianRöling Minecraft Premium was the name of the paid Minecraft license back when they still offered a free version before 2015. see https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/428478-minecraft-java-edition-account-types for more info.

Comment: From the question it seems like the asker doesn't play Minecraft for 4+ years already.

Comment: If for whatever reason OP doesn't want to set the Server to online mode, there are plugins that allow for password-authentication functionality.

Comment: You can also enable the whitelist.

Comment: @Baumi Um... Whitelists won't work if the user can be literally anyone on that list.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of banning the username, try banning the IP that the player is logging onto your server through. You'll see it in the server log.

Unless they can somehow change their IP, which we hope is not the case, they should have a harder time getting onto your server.

Comment: You can change your IP by unplugging and replugging in your router, which takes about 2 minutes to do.